# Why recursive grep does not work with STDOUT?

Tags: grep

I've been long used to have some custom aliases in my Ubuntu/Mint machines, like `alias grep='grep -irn --color --line-buffered'`. However, I've noticed that since a while ago this stopped working for piped outputs.

Trying to debug, I've noticed the problematic option is the recursive one, and instead of grep'ping the STDOUT it searches from the current directory - recursively.

I'm currently running grep 2.16, and I've found a machine that's working as I expected running 2.10.

Example:
`tail -f /var/log/xxx.log | grep -irn yyy`

What has been changed that `-r`/`-d recurse` makes grep search for a folder instead of following the `man` directory option?

```
-d ACTION, --directories=ACTION
    If an input file is a directory, use ACTION to process it.
    [...] If ACTION is recurse, read all files under each directory, recursively,
    following symbolic links only if they are on the command line. This is
    equivalent to the -r option.
```

Comment: Exactly what is the behavior you want? I don't understand how you want `grep` to read its _output_.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is more suitable for a comment but it would be too long so I'm posting it as an answer.

grep behavior piqued my interest and I think that OP is on the right track, I also found that newer versions of grep behave differently than older ones. In older versions if you didn't pass a parameter when using `-r` it only searched for a pattern in standard input as it should according to the documentation: `grep searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are named, or if a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name) for lines containing a match to the given pattern`. In newer versions however it's searching for a pattern in the current directory even if you didn't provide any filename. Check this:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/grep-test
$ cd /tmp/grep-test
$ echo pam > FILE
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.10
(...)
$ grep pam -r
pam
pam
$ /home/ja/grep/grep-2.16/src/grep pam -r
FILE:pam
```

I didn't find anything mention of any changes related to this in grep changelog apart from [this](https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7207):

> ** Changes in behavior
>
> The -r (--recursive) option now follows only command-line symlinks. 
>   Also, by default -r now reads a device only if it is named on the
>   command   line; this can be overridden with --devices.  -R acts as
>   before, so   use -R if you prefer the old behavior of following all
>   symlinks and   defaulting to reading all devices.

It's still a matter of question why OP wants to search standard output recursively, but definitely something changed in grep.

Comment: It's not that I want to explicitly search STDOUT recursively; as I said in the beginning, I'm used to some aliases to make my grep life easier - and to reduce the number of aliases, `-r` was left in the main one - allowing me to easily run `tail -f file.log | grep` instead of `tail -f file.log | grep -in --color --line-buffered`, or simply `grep XXX old.log`.

Comment: But...  Could that be considered a bug of some sort?

Comment: Maybe. You can get more luck asking this question on grep mailing list.